# React-admin - How can I force the Dasbhoard to ask for login if not authenticated

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-router, react-admin

In the Admin component I would like to have a dashboard like so:

```
<Admin dashboard={Dashboard}>
    <Resource name="list" list={MyList} />
</Admin>
```

How can I force the dashboard to ask for login if the user is not already authenticated? Is there an easy way to achieve this?

Comment: A few days ago there was another answer about using react HOC components to achieve a login, but the answer seems to be deleted. If somebody could undelete it, it would be great. I think that answer was really helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When an api endpoint returns a 401 or 403 http statuscode react-admin will show the login page.
From the [Authentication page](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Authentication.html) in the react-admin documentation:

> By default, an react-admin app doesn’t require authentication. But if
> the REST API ever returns a 401 (Unauthorized) or a 403 (Forbidden)
> response, then the user is redirected to the /login route. You have
> nothing to do - it’s already built in.

The authentication is configure by the authProvider prop.

```
<Admin dashboard={Dashboard} authProvider={authProvider}>
    <Resource name="list" list={MyList} />
</Admin>
```

The auth provider is called each time the user navigates.
So you can implement your authProvider which checks if the user is logged or rout to the login page.

From the [Authentication page - Checking Credentials During Navigation](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Authentication.html#checking-credentials-during-navigation):

> Redirecting to the login page whenever a REST response uses a 401
> status code is usually not enough, because react-admin keeps data on
> the client side, and could display stale data while contacting the
> server - even after the credentials are no longer valid.
>
> Fortunately, each time the user navigates, react-admin calls the
> authProvider with the AUTH_CHECK type, so it’s the ideal place to
> check for credentials.

Comment: Since no REST API call is done from the Dashboard, how can I trigger a 401 or 403 from the Dashboard page? Or is there another way to force a login before the Dashboard is accessed?

Comment: Finally, I've decided not to use any dashboard for now, but I think indeed the AUTH_CHECK is the way to go. Thanks @And-y, I should have read the documentation more carefully.